# Frequent disconnections from games

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Netgear 2000 WNR v3 and lately, every time I try and play any online game, i'll be able to play for a few minutes then it will disconnect me. I still can access the internet, but videos won't stream all that well. But if I just connect through my cable modem my everything works fine. What's wrong?

Comment: The obligatory [long answer](http://www.tomshardware.com/picturestory/571-wi-fi-beamforming-networking.html).

Comment: I had the same problem after my mom got a new laptop. I had to reset the router getting rid of all settings completely. It kind of sucked but it fixed it.... never back to perfect speed but at like 98% of original.